# Json Parse android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Hi guys i got a json string like

```
{
"Successful": true,
"Value": "{\"MesajTipi\":1,\"Mesaj\":\"{\\\"Yeni\\\":\\\"Hayır\\\",\\\"Oid\\\":\\\"3d9b81c9-b7b3-4316-8a73-ad4d54ee02a8\\\",\\\"OzelKod\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Adet\\\":1,\\\"ProblemTanimi\\\":\\\"999\\\",\\\"HataTespitYeri\\\":\\\"Montajda\\\",\\\"Tekrar\\\":\\\"Evet\\\",\\\"ResmiBildirimNo\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Malzeme\\\":\\\"5475ffdb-0bc0-49cb-9186-429c60dbf91b\\\",\\\"HataKodu\\\":\\\"c30df623-496b-4a62-ba16-493bd435ca33\\\",\\\"Tarih\\\":\\\"2016-04-16 10:34:00\\\",\\\"KayitNo\\\":\\\"1600010.2\\\"}\"}"
}
```

I need to get "Oid" value from this string.
I tried to get it with

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parse = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonobj = (JsonObject) parse.parse(snc);
            String stroid = jsonobj.get("Oid").toString();
```

But it gives null referance exception ? Any idea how can i get the only Oid value ?

***Edit***

I already tried [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) but still no succes

What i tried from this page :

```
String pageName = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Value").getJSONObject("Mesaj").getString("Oid");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of extra `" "` in the `"Value"` section of JSON, so it will be treated as String not an object. The better solution is to seek the source of the JSON to see why they added extra `" "` and clear that but if you don't have access the source I propose the following:

Replace:

```
String stroid = jsonobj.get("Oid").toString();
```

with:

```
String valueString = jsonobj.getString("Value");
jsonobj = new JSONObject(valueString);
String mesagString = jsonobj.getString("Mesaj");
jsonobj = new JSONObject(mesagString);
String stroid = jsonobj.getInt("Oid").toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say this is your JSON

```
{
"success":"ok",
"test" : [{"id" : "1" ,"name" : "first"}]
,"RPTF":
    [{"cats":[{"id" : "1" ,"name" : "first"},
              {"id" : "1" ,"name" : "first"},
              {"id" : "2" ,"name" : "test"} ]


    ,"pics" : [{"id" : "12" ,"value" : "description" ,"src" : "http://citygram.ir" ,"visit" : "3" },
               {"id" : "10" ,"value" : "description" ,"src" : "http://citygram.ir" ,"visit" : "3" } ]
  }]
}
```

method number one (if you want to access  "success")

```
    public String jsonOne(String json, String target) {

    String result;
    try {

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
        result = jo.getString(target);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        return "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

you can simply call this method like this

```
jsonOne(String json, "success");
```

method number two (in case you want to access "id"s inside the "test")

```
public String[] jsonTwo(String json, String target0, String target1) {

    String[] result;
    result = new String[1];

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray(target0);

        result = new String[ja.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jojo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            result[i] = jojo.getString(target1);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

you get an array String on call :

```
jsonTwo(String json, "test", "id");
```

method number three (let's say you want to access "value"s in side "pics")

```
public String[] jsonThree(String json, String target0, String target1,String target2) {

    String[] result;
    result = new String[1];

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray(target0);
        JSONObject jojo=ja.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray jaja=jojo.getJSONArray(target1);

        result = new String[jaja.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jojojo = jaja.getJSONObject(i);
            result[i] = jojojo.getString(target2);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        toast("Wrong");
    }

    return result;
}
```

on call :

```
jsonThree(String json, "RPTF", "pics", "value");
```

you can write more methods like this and just call them .